# What is the equivalent of Newtonsoft.Json's JsonProperty attribute in System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, system.text.json

What is the equivalent of Newtonsoft.Json's `JsonProperty` attribute in System.Text.Json?

Example:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Example
{
    [JsonProperty("test2")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

References:

- [Newtonsoft.Json JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm)
- [Using Newtonsoft.Json attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GenerateWithJsonNetAttributes.htm)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The property is named `JsonPropertyName` and comes from `System.Text.Json.Serialization` in the `System.Text.Json` package. The functionality is natively available in .NET 3.1 or later.

Example:

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Example
{
    [JsonPropertyName("test2")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

References:

- [Try the new System.Text.Json APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/)
- [JsonProperty.Name Property --> Not yet documented properly...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonproperty.name?view=netcore-3.0)

Answer (score 10):

Note for anyone who finds this looking to replace Newtonsoft with `System.Text.Json` specifically getting a **private** property to serialize. Newtonsoft will happily serialize a private property with the `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty` attribute, but putting `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName` on a private property doesn't work. For example:

```cs
enum Animal { Cat, Dog }
class Foo
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("animals")]
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("animals")]
    private string AnimalForSerializer
    {
        get => AnimalForMe.ToString() + "s";
        set => AnimalForMe = Enum.Parse<Animal>(value.TrimEnd('s'));
    }
 
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public Animal AnimalForMe { get; set; }
}

var b = new Foo { AnimalForMe = Animal.Dog };

var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(b);
var fromJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(json);
Console.WriteLine($"{json} -> {fromJson.AnimalForMe}");

json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b);
fromJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
Console.WriteLine($"{json} -> {fromJson.AnimalForMe}");
```

Outputs

```
{} -> Cat
{"animals":"Dogs"} -> Dog
```

To replace this behavior you need [JsonInclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonincludeattribute?view=net-6.0). Or rather, to almost replace. The `System.Text.Json` team decided not to support private properties. If you try you will get an error like "The non-public property 'AnimalForSerializer' on type 'Foo' is annotated with 'JsonIncludeAttribute' which is invalid.". But you can have a private setter, apparently:

```cs
class Foo
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("animals")]
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("animals")]
    public string AnimalForSerializer
    {
        get => AnimalForMe.ToString() + "s";
        private set => AnimalForMe = Enum.Parse<Animal>(value.TrimEnd('s'));
    }
    
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public Animal AnimalForMe { get; set; }
}

var b = new Foo { AnimalForMe = Animal.Dog };

var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(b);
var fromJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(json);
Console.WriteLine($"{json} -> {fromJson.AnimalForMe}");

json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b);
fromJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
Console.WriteLine($"{json} -> {fromJson.AnimalForMe}");
```

Outputs

```
{"animals":"Dogs"} -> Dog
{"animals":"Dogs"} -> Dog
```

Of course, not having `private` breaks encapsulation, but what can you do.

Answer (score 0):

I have just upgraded a production application (that fetches Json from Workday) to .Net 8.0 from .Net 6.0 and now JsonPropertyName no longer works on a public property for me. I switched to NewtonSoft and it works again.